# Can php have multiple doctypes?

Tags: php, html, web

I am new to web design and had a question. I am reading the Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript: With jQuery, CSS & HTML5 (Learning Php, Mysql, Javascript, Css & Html5" and in his example program at the end he has a "setup.php" and at the beginning he starts with a DOCTYPE HTML. Is this how all html should really be expressed? I understand you can have each type of scripts in each file but confused on that its a .php with a doctype html. Any info is greatly appreciated. The stack overflow code is making it hard to show the start of the code on the page.

```
<!--<!DOCTYPE html>--!>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Setting up database</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h3>Setting up...</h3>

<?php // Example 27-3: setup.php
  require_once 'functions.php';

  createTable('members',
              'user VARCHAR(16),
              pass VARCHAR(16),
              INDEX(user(6))');

  createTable('messages', 
              'id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
              auth VARCHAR(16),
              recip VARCHAR(16),
              pm CHAR(1),
              time INT UNSIGNED,
              message VARCHAR(4096),
              INDEX(auth(6)),
              INDEX(recip(6))');

  createTable('friends',
              'user VARCHAR(16),
              friend VARCHAR(16),
              INDEX(user(6)),
              INDEX(friend(6))');

  createTable('profiles',
              'user VARCHAR(16),
              text VARCHAR(4096),
              INDEX(user(6))');
?>

    <br>...done.
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This appears to be part of a PHP script that is ultimately outputting an HTML document, that is the final result sent to the browser will just contain HTML (and possibly JavaScript and CSS) and so it should contain at the top `<!DOCTYPE html>` specifying that what follows is an HTML5 document (there are other earlier HTML versions). Right now you have `<!--<!DOCTYPE html>--!>`, which is essentially commenting this out.

Comment: Ultimately the browser does not care whether it was a PHP or PYTHON script that created the HTML or whether it came from a *static file* of fixed HTML. All that matters is what the final output is, which is HTML. So the DOCTYPE specification is only applicable to HTML documents and has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Every HTML pages start with this: `<!DOCTYPE html>` (here you indicate to your browser that the page is HTML 5).
You have several doctype, but there are now no longer used because they are based on old specification (such as HTML4, XHTML, etc).

Even if you use a PHP to generate a webpage, they must start with: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Because PHP only interprets the code and produces, in your case you always have an HTML page, so he must start with the doctype.

Later you should learn how to create a class in PHP, this class should only contain PHP code, so you don't have to include the doctype.

Here is the conclusion:

- If you have in your PHP file a complete HTML page (with an HTML tag, a body tag, and a header tag) you must use the doctype
- If you have only PHP code, you don't need to use the doctype (because you don't have any HTML code in it)

Comment: Just to clarify, it is the *outputted HTML* that gets generated that should begin with `<!DOCTYPE html>` (assuming the document is HTML5, that is), not necessarily the PHP page itself.